# Why hbase stop all HMaster service first when rolling restart in rolling-restart.sh

Tags: hbase

I read the rolling-restart.sh in $HBASE_HOME/bin, found that the script would stop all master service (including the backup ones) at the same time, and then restart them both:

```
# The content of rolling-restart.sh
...
# stop all masters before re-start to avoid races for master znode
"$bin"/hbase-daemon.sh --config "${HBASE_CONF_DIR}" stop master
"$bin"/hbase-daemons.sh --config "${HBASE_CONF_DIR}" \
  --hosts "${HBASE_BACKUP_MASTERS}" stop master-backup

# make sure the master znode has been deleted before continuing
zmaster=`$bin/hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.HBaseConfTool zookeeper.znode.master`
...

# all masters are down, now restart
"$bin"/hbase-daemon.sh --config "${HBASE_CONF_DIR}" ${START_CMD_DIST_MODE} master
"$bin"/hbase-daemons.sh --config "${HBASE_CONF_DIR}" \
  --hosts "${HBASE_BACKUP_MASTERS}" ${START_CMD_DIST_MODE} master-backup
```

In this way the HMaster service would be unavailable during this period. Why it's not designed in a more graceful way:

- Stop the backup master, and then restart it
- Stop the active master, then the backup master would become active
- start the original active one of master, now it's the backup one

I have tested it on my own cluster and work fine. Is this more graceful? Or I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't know the intentions of the authors of the rolling-restart.sh script, it also doesn't make much sense to me. I also perform a master-by-master stop and start and it works just fine.

When you turn one master node off at a time, the only thing you need to take care of is that the entry in the Zookeeper node '/hbase/backup-masters' is empty (hence the backup master really took over as active master) before you turn on the previously active master node again.

I observed that if you turn on the previously active master node on again before its Zookeeper session expired, the backup master will never take over and the previously active master will spent an awful lot of time in the "Initialize ServerManager" status  (see below) and every interaction with Hbase will fail with the "org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RemoteWithExtrasException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.ServerNotRunningYetException: Server is not running yet"  Exception.

| Start Time | Description | State | Status | Completion Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sat Apr 15 17:17:36 UTC 2023 | Master startup | RUNNING (since 15mins, 47sec ago) | Initialize ServerManager and schedule SCP for crash servers (since 15mins, 47sec ago) | RUNNING |